# My I-20 expired and I lost my Indian passport

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

My I-20 expired and I lost my Indian passport. I have applied for the new passport but the application was not accepted because of the expired I-20. What do I do?

Comment: Get in touch with the consulate and ask for advice. If nothing else they should be able to issue you with an emergency travel document to get you back to India.

Comment: VTC: unclear what is not being accepted... the application for the new passport or the extending the I-20; OP has not returned since posting.